# htaccess rewriting issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

Working on a website, and having some problems with `.htaccess`.

I do have a category link, which is like this:

```
sharing/index.php?cf=category&id=$1
```

I did a rewrite on it to:

```
sharing/cat-([^/]+)$
```

which works very well, then I added a pagination to the script, and pagination in the link is like this:

```
sharing/cat-1?next=1
```

I would like to make it like this:

```
sharing/cat-1/page/1
```

I have tried my best, but it didn't work out. Please note `cat-1` is for the category ID meaning in another category it may be `cat-3`.

Comment: Show us what have you tried, so we can help to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you haven't escaped the forward-slash.

So you should try this for the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^sharing\/cat-([^\/]+)\/page\/([0-9]*)$ sharing/index.php?cf=category&id=$1&next=$2
```

And the link for the pagination, should be like this:

```
sharing/cat-1/page/1
```

not the one you mention (`sharing/cat-1?next=1`)

Remember that if your categories are only numbers, it might be better to change `([^\/]+)` by `([0-9]*)`

Comment: You have to change the link too. Make it 'sharing/cat-1/page/1'

Comment: sowi my bad, i made a mistake its fine now, thanks i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example, where I'm passing two variables:

```
RewriteRule ^player/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ players/view.php?player=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

For extending it, you just need to add **([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/** to the URL, and pass another parameter in the other side.